# Remove redundant sublists within list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, duplicates

Hello everyone I have a list of lists values such as :

```
list_of_values=[['A','B'],['A','B','C'],['D','E'],['A','C'],['I','J','K','L','M'],['J','M']]
```

and I would like to keep within that list, only the lists where I have the highest amount of values.

For instance in `sublist1` : `['A','B']` **A** and **B** are also present in the `sublist2` `['A','B','C']`, so I remove the `sublist1`.
The same for `sublist4`.
the `sublist6` is also removed because **J** and **M** were present in a the longer `sublist5`.
at the end I should get:

```
list_of_no_redundant_values=[['A','B','C'],['D','E'],['I','J','K','L','M']]
```

other exemple =

```
list_of_values=[['A','B'],['A','B','C'],['B','E'],['A','C'],['I','J','K','L','M'],['J','M']]
```

expected output :

```
[['A','B','C'],['B','E'],['I','J','K','L','M']]
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: What output would you expect if you had the input `[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'F']]` ? Is there a guarantee that the elements of the smaller lists won't be split among many different big lists?

Comment: The expected here would be  to keep all list since all ```['A', 'B', 'D']``` are not all present into ```['A', 'C', 'D', 'E'] ```, same for ```'B', 'F']```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mylist=[['A','B'],['A','C'],['A','B','C'],['D','E'],['I','J','K','L','M'],['J','M']]
def remove_subsets(lists):
    outlists = lists[:]
    for s1 in lists:
        for s2 in lists:
            if set(s1).issubset(set(s2)) and (s1 is not s2):
                outlists.remove(s1)
                break
    return outlists
print(remove_subsets(mylist))
```

This should result in `[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']]`

Comment: @Grendel, there was a minor bug in that code. I have updated it with the fix. Please check it out.

Comment: Is it normal I get : ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list for other data?

Comment: @Grendel There was a `break` missing. The loop continues to check and if there was a match again, then you would hit the issue you have mentioned. I have updated the answer to correct the same.